# two responsive divs not lining up

Tags: css, html

I need two columns of divs that are responsive and collapse under each other as screen size goes down. They should always be centered. But no matter what I do I can't make these divs sit next to each other. It must all be inline CSS.

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">

<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%;">left div</div>
<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%;">right div</div>

<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%;">left div</div>
<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%;">right div</div>

<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%;">left div</div>
<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%;">right div</div>

</div>
```

I have tried changing the left and right divs to width 42% which means they sit next to each other, but it squishes up those divs when viewed on a table or phone. They should be full width when it collapses down to one column on a mobile device.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be better..

Comment: `#container > .block { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is achieved on `width: 42%` then all the divs probably have some margins and/or padding.
Total horizontal dimension of an element is measured by its *width* + *padding* + *margin*. So, when you set `width: 50%` in the result you got 50% + padding + margin, so there's no way to fit two divs in one line.
If you set

```
<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">left div</div>
<div class="block" style="float: left; width:50%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">right div</div>
```

for all your `divs` you should be fine.

To change the layout to one column on particular resolution you need to introduce `media-query`. For example:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    div.block {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Of course, the `max-width` value depends on what devices you're aiming at. Here are some example resolutions of some popular mobile devices:

- iPhone (up to 5s) portrait - **320px**
- iPhone (up to 4s) landscape - **470px**
- iPhone 5/5s landscape - **560px**
- Samsung Galaxy S3 portrait - **360px**
- Samsung Galaxy S3 landscape - **640px**
- tablet portrait (most of them) - **760px**
- tablet landscape (most of them) - **960px**

Comment: This has helped a lot! Didn't know about element width measurement. Can media-query be added inline? All this gets exported to other sites and must be inline. What is the best default media-query to use?

Comment: You can't add it in the `style` attribute but if you are able to modify the HTML markup, you can do it like in my example (I edited it). Simply add the `<style>...</style>` section to the HTML.

Comment: Is there any other option for this? I can't seem to get the media-query working despite having access to HTML markup.

Comment: You probably did something wrong. It should work. Show me the exact HTML that you added

Comment: Full copy of all HTML here: http://pastebin.com/jKtZ3z1s Its taken from the HTML description editor of Magento.

Comment: Your standard styles are injected inline (in `style` attribute) so they will never be overriden by those from `<style>...</style>`. To resolve this remove all inline styles from `.block` divs and add them to the `<style>...</style>` like this: `.block { width: 50%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was trying other modes of support that didn't end up working. I have edited the code as suggested and removed all 'style' attributes from the '.block' but it isn't working. New paste bin: http://pastebin.com/2GEa8iUs

Comment: @bennygill could you please put that code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Then it would be much easier to examine it.

Comment: Got it working! I'm not sure what was happening before but now its fine, I can fiddle with the @media attribute and its all good. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RrVLx/)

```
.block{
    float: left; width:49%; //Change this to 50%
    border: 1px solid green;  //Change to 0px
}

.left{
    text-align: left;
}

.right{
    text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="block right">left div</div>
    <div class="block left">right div</div>
    <div class="block right">left div</div>
    <div class="block left">right div</div>
    <div class="block right">left div</div>
    <div class="block left">right div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GkTqZ/2/)
The divs are sitting next to each other?
Perhaps they are inheriting some other css and are given a margin or padding from parent elements.
Try `margin: 0; padding: 0;`

To make them 100% on smaller screen you have to use [**media queries**](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)
for instance:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .block {
          width: 100%;
      }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit.